# Как подсчитать количество наборов в списке товаров?

Tags: javascript

Есть список категорий:  салаты, закуски, супы, в каждой категории по 6 товаров, далее есть набор из категорий, содержит 2 категории и по условию в наборе может содержаться салат или закуска, и суп. Вопрос: пользователь набрал товаров из этих категорий, и я знаю сколько товаров каждой категории он выбрал, мне нужно рассчитать количество наборов, плюс набор может быть не полный (например выбран только суп). Пытаюсь реализовать данную вещь на javascript

Нужно пройтись по все товарам в корзине и получить количество наборов,
например набор лайт содержит салат или закуску и суп. Как это сделать?

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: и что вы уже напытались?

Comment: Я так понял, что раз суп - обязательная составляющая набора, то количество наборов равно количеству супов.

Comment: да, правильно, я тоже подумал что нашел ответ, но это правильно работает при идеальных условиях, если  пользователь выбрал суп и салат это один полный набор, а если он выбрал еще закуску то это еще один набор, но не полный(так как не хватает супа), и как подсчитать количество таких наборов

Comment: @Ajlelcc: Вам нужно четко сформировать правила формирования ваших наборов. Я вижу что вы сами не до конца их осознаете, а мы тем более.

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть наоборот, каждый товар относится к какой-то категории. Может как-то так? Кривовато конечно получилось, но...

```
// var товар = {название, категория, ...};

var категории = ['суп','салат',...];
var наборы = {
    '0' : {
        категория[0],
        категория[1]
    },
    '1' : {
        категория[1]
    }
};
var задействованные_категории = {};

for(var p in список_выбранных_товаров){
    var товар = список_выбранных_товаров[p];
    if(!задействованные_категории[товар.категория_к_которой_он_относится]){
        задействованные_категории[товар.категория_к_которой_он_относится] = 0;
    }
    задействованные_категории[товар.категория_к_которой_он_относится]++;
}

var необходимые_наборы = {};
for(var n in наборы){ // по наборам
    var набор = наборы[i];

    var будем_учитывать_этот_набор = true;
    for(var c in набор){ // по категориям
        var категория = набор[c];
        if(!задействованные_категории[категория]){
            будем_учитывать_этот_набор = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(будем_учитывать_этот_набор){
        if(!необходимые_наборы[n]){
            необходимые_наборы[n] = 0
        }
        необходимые_наборы[n]++;
        for(var c in набор){
            var категория = набор[c];
            задействованные_категории[категория]--;
        }
    }
}

// выводим количество
for(var n in необходимые_наборы){
    console.log('Набор #'+n+': '+необходимые_наборы[n]);
}
```